# Не работают промисы( Подскажите что делаю не так?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

Вызываю этот метод на хуке `created`
Срабатывает блок `else` должно вернуть значение(число) с сервера, но это происходит только после второго обновления. При первом возвращает старое. Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка?
Доп. код готов предоставить

```
methods: {
    zeroTest() {
      // объект с ключами всех дат по записям пользователя
      const keysDates = this.infoCurrentUser.userСalories;

      /* Получаем ключ последней даты записанной в бд, и переворачиваем его,
    для того чтобы корректно распарсить. */
      const lastRecordedDate = Object.keys(keysDates)[Object.keys(keysDates).length - 1].split('-')
        .reverse()
        .join('-');

      // Возвращаю кол-во миллисекунд последней даты в бд
      const lastDateMseconds = Date.parse(lastRecordedDate);

      // Получаю текущую дату в нужно формате для дельнейшего парсинга.
      const currentData = new Date().toLocaleString().slice(0, 10).split('.')
        .reverse()
        .join('.');

      // Возвращаю кол-во миллисекунд текущей даты
      const currentDataMseconds = Date.parse(currentData);

      // Если текущая дата больше последней, обнуляем счетчик кал.
      if (currentDataMseconds > lastDateMseconds) {
        this.caloriesPerDay = 0;
      } else {
        // В противном случае записываем значение из бд
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          resolve(this.infoCurrentUser.userСalories[
            Object.keys(keysDates)[Object.keys(keysDates).length - 1]]
            .caloriesEatenPerDay);
        }).then((el) => console.log(el));
      }
      return 0;
    },
```

Comment: код нужно вставить как код, а не картинка.

Comment: где именно используется данный блок кода? Куда возвращается значение?

Comment: @Grundy вставил как код) Данный блок используется в методе, и вызывается на хуке `created`. Значение хотя бы получить в консоль, а потом уже запишу в переменную

Comment: как именно zeroTest вызывается? Почему ты думаешь, что именно `else` блок выполняется?

Comment: @Grundy сделал только что проверку, `console.log('Выполнился блок else')` он и сработал.

Comment: @Grundy `created() {
    this.zeroTest();
  },`

Comment: какая версия `vue`?

Comment: Не вижу у вас в коде обращения к серверу

Comment: А что будет, если lastDateMseconds===undefined? Выполнится ветка else.